# Shrink caption to size of image

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to tell my `span` to wrap before it increases the size of its parent `div`?

My mockup: https://codepen.io/bukzor/pen/xzLYzj

The colored blocks are images of undefined size, and the white blocks should be floating next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the year 2018, we have [`display:grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which provides an elegant solution.

```
figure {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://codepen.io/bukzor/pen/qKXyKW

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this without adding a specific width to each `div.shrink` element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e52pZ/2/

If the IMG size is a complete unknown, and will always be different, you could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('.shrink').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.width(self.find('img').width())
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e52pZ/7/

Comment: On a scale of one to infinity, how certain are you that you can't do this with just css/html ?

Comment: Though I'm not Bart, I did try for quite a while, using various shrink wrapping techniques, etc. My certainty (on a scale of 1 to 10 -- sorry, I don't know what to do with infinity): 8. Hopefully someone will prove me wrong. I'd /love/ for this to be possible with only pure CSS & HTML. =)

Comment: On a scale of 1 to infinity... I am half way between 1 and infinity. ;)

Comment: I updated my jQuery snippet and fiddle link. Previous code didn't do quite what I expected it to. This one looks good.

Answer (score 1):

A property of "display:table-cell" seems to get a *little* closer. It needs more work by people that know more than me though.

http://jsfiddle.net/e52pZ/12/

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this one out.  The trick is to use display: table, and on the caption use the often forgotten display: table-caption.  I made a pen here: http://codepen.io/jhereg00/pen/qEGzob

It's basically this:

```
<figure>
  <img>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

with

```
figure {
  display: table;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

Or, in order to style the container as you did in your fiddle, you'll need to add another wrapping div, like I did in my pen.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Sorry it took two years to see your answer. `table-caption` is a bit wonky because it promotes itself to a sibling of its parent, making styling a bit awkward, as you noted. It's a good solution, but I like `inline-grid` even better.